# Android: unable to pass a url in webview

Tags: android, webview

i am trying to pass a url which start with www.example.com/xxxxxxx in my webview it can be anything in the place of xxxxxxx. see the code you will understand

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://www.example.com"+"*")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

i want to pass any url from my website only else open it in default browser.

Answer (score 0):

`Uri.getHost()` return the [host from the authority](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getHost%28%29), you should try to use `if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com"))` or `if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("example.com"))`.

Also, as a good practice, you should reverse your `equals()` statement like this: `"example.com".equals(Uri.parse(url).getHost())` as you know that `"example.com"` will never be `null` and, as such, never throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: it is not passing all url's of my website hence it contain many pages and it is not possible to specify all url by adding or statement